# Webserver Usage Statistics / # of Apache Installations

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, web-server, usage

Does anyone know a site that details webserver usage statistics in the form of how many websites run Apache, how many IIS, how many Apache on Windows and how many on Linux?

I think it should be possible because AFAIK it is written in the HTTP header returned by the webserver or otherwise HTTP error / index pages may give a clue.

Addendum: what about the Operating System part?

Thanks for the Netcraft site, it is perfect for the Apache / IIS distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, [Netcraft](http://www.netcraft.com) has been doing this for a long time...

Here's the latest:
http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2009/08/31/august_2009_web_server_survey.html

Answer (score 0):

[Netcraft August 2009 Web Server Survey](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/web_server_survey.html)

Comment: For OS: http://leb.net/hzo/ioscount/data/r.9904.txt

Comment: The OS data from April 1999 might be a little dated, though. ;-)

Comment: Possibly! :)  Problem is this is the kind of survey companies want to charge for, not make available for free on the net.